# Vertical Tab in Java and MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, unicode

I'm using Java to insert data into MYSQL Tables, one column requires data to have Vertical Tab sign in it ([VT](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+240B)).

I did the same with php code and it is pretty simple by just writing "\v", the data looks like this in the table:
[image]

The problem starts as java does not allow "\v", so i tried to encode the character the following way:

```
byte[] utf8bytes = { (byte)0xE2, (byte)0x90, (byte)0x8B };
Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
String string = new String ( utf8bytes, utf8charset );
....
MysqlDataSource DATA_SOURCE = new MysqlDataSource();
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql_statement, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
....
statement.setString(index++, (String) string);
.....
```

While this works the final data in the table itself results in a "?".
[image]

I also tried to set the charset for the MysqlDataSource but in this case it doesn't accept the encoded character and the statement fails.

```
try {
     DATA_SOURCE.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xE2\xAD\xBFdat...
```

I hope you can help me to find the correct way to insert a Vertical Tab into the table.

Comment: E2808B is "ZERO WIDTH SPACE".

Comment: The `?` comes from not using utf8 throughout.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

I checked the data inserted by the existing php solution of a single Vertical Tab on byte level in the database table:

```
SELECT hex(example_column) FROM `example_table` WHERE 1
```

Result: [image: VT from \v]

Which we can easily reproduce using the example code i posted above:

```
byte[] utf8bytes = { (byte)0x0B};
String string = new String ( utf8bytes );
```